# pandas replace "/n" and take the balance data to new cell

Tags: pandas

I am having following data in text file.

```
607 1800.00
608 +1%
609 0.0
610 0\n09:20:00
```

I want "/n" to go away and the 09:22:03 should come in the new line of 611. Thanks.

Comment: In the title and your question, you have /n, but in the quoted part you have \n. Which is it?

Comment: Ohh sorry, I might have been confused. So I rectified it at the time of capturing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the literal `\n` two characters in your file, you can split on it, then `explode` to new rows and reincrement the first column:

```
(pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep='\s+', header=None, names=['A', 'B'], dtype={'B': 'string'})
   .assign(B=lambda d: d['B'].str.split(r'\\n'))
   .explode('B')
   .assign(A=lambda d: d['A']+d['A'].diff().eq(0).cumsum())
   .to_csv('out.csv', sep=' ', index=False, header=None)
)
```

Output file:

```
607 1800.00
608 +1%
609 0.0
610 0
611 09:20:00
```